# Formik handle checkbox validation with React and Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formik

I'm trying to handle the Checkbox validation for an "Accept Terms of Service" checkbox with React and Material UI.

So far I did this:

Validation Schema

```js
const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup
    .string()
    .email('Enter a valid email address')
    .required('Email address is required'),
  password: yup
    .string()
    .min(8, 'Password should be of minimum 8 characters')
    .required(),
  termsOfService: yup
    .boolean()
    .required('You must accept the Terms of Service to proceed')
    .oneOf([true], 'Error')
})
```

Form Component

```js
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      termsOfService: false
    },
    validationSchema,
    onSubmit: async values => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2))
    }
  })
```

Form Component JSX

```js
<Box
      component="form"
      noValidate
      onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}
      sx={{ mt: 1 }}
    >
      <TextField
        autoFocus
        margin="normal"
        required
        fullWidth
        id="email"
        label={t('email_address')}
        name="email"
        autoComplete="email"
        value={formik.values.email}
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        error={formik.touched.email && Boolean(formik.errors.email)}
        helperText={formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email}
      />
      <TextField
        margin="normal"
        required
        fullWidth
        name="password"
        label={t('password')}
        type="password"
        id="password"
        autoComplete="current-password"
        value={formik.values.password}
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        error={formik.touched.password && Boolean(formik.errors.password)}
        helperText={formik.touched.password && formik.errors.password}
      />
      <FormControlLabel
        control={<Checkbox value="terms-of-service" color="primary" />}
        label={t('terms_of_service')}
      />
      <Button type="submit" fullWidth variant="contained" sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}>
        {t('sign_up_button')}
      </Button>
    </Box>
```

How to do that, in the same way, I managed the validation on the text inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-mui-v5-forked-ykdjob?file=/src/App.js)

You can use `formik.setFieldValue` inside `onChange` event of checkbox to set checkbox value. Also, use mui `FormHelperText` to show validation error.

```
<FormControl>
    <FormControlLabel
      control={
         <Checkbox
           onChange={(e) => { setFieldValue("termsOfService", e.target.checked) }}
           name="termsOfService"
           checked={values.termsOfService}
          />
      }
      label="terms_of_service"
    >
    <FormHelperText style={{ color: "red" }}>
       {touched.termsOfService && errors.termsOfService
        ? touched.termsOfService && errors.termsOfService
        : " "}
    </FormHelperText>
</FormControl>
```